# How to change color of selected images in ListView when Contextual Action Mode is active?

Tags: android

I want the image of the selected ListView items to have a tint of blue, like the rest of the ListView items have. How can it be achieved?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: show your adapter class

Comment: @HimanshuShekherJha I used this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab

Comment: are you calling notifyDataSetChanged(); as it shown in adapter class

Comment: @HimanshuShekherJha Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the tint of images in selected list items, I added a few things in **getView()** method of the adapter. Here's my **getView()** method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Removing tint from images just in case view is recycled
    if (convertView != null) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setColorFilter(null);
    }

    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    //Here selectedItemsPosition is a TreeSet of Integer storing all selected item positions
    if (selectedItemsPosition != null && selectedItemsPosition.contains(position)) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setColorFilter(
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLightBlue),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
        );
    }

    return view;
}
```

Here is the screenshot:  [image]

Here is the full example: [Github](https://github.com/mohdali6/Android-Contextual-ActionBar-Example/tree/feature-tint-list-item-images)